# Can't escape from eval with next using Pry-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, pry-rails

Hi I've installed Pry to do some awesome debugging and had it working before but when I step into the code with 'next' I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (eval):2: Can't escape from eval with next
```

Code being used:

```
def create
    binding.pry
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: i think it's saying that you placed debugger inside a block that's being passed to eval

Comment: What does that mean to eval?

Comment: can you paste the code where you added `binding.pry`?

Comment: i have no idea.  a quick google of the error shows an unresolved ticket https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav/issues/20

Comment: Yeah I saw that as well, so confused, I love PRY but I cannot use it I get the same issue everytime I put it in

Comment: try specifying a specific gem version and see what works.

Answer (score 71):

Please make sure to install the 'pry-nav' gem.

I had the same error because I made the assumption that navigation commands were included into the 'pry-rails' gem.

Add `gem 'pry-nav'` in your Gemfile, then run `bundle install`.

Comment: How is this answer not everywhere?

Comment: On [pry-nav](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav) pages it is now suggested to use [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) gem (for Ruby >= 2.0) or [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) gem (for Ruby <= 1.9).

Comment: Didn't work for me. I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 28):

You can now use [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) gem (for Ruby >= 2.0) or [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) gem (for Ruby <= 1.9).

Use it together with `pry` gem in your Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-byebug'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, in my case the problem was solved because I needed to require those gems. For example:

```
group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'pry',                                require: true
  gem 'pry-byebug',                         require: true
  gem 'pry-doc',                            require: true
  gem 'rspec-rails',                        require: false
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved the problem. Even the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791440/5669031) didn't work for me.

I had to add `require 'pry-byebug'` to my spec file!

Answer (score -3):

I believe the issue here is that you're debugging inside a block, so you cannot call `next` while you're inside of it.